# How Try and Catch command Use in Azure Data factory pipline?

Tags: sql, azure, try-catch, azure-data-factory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gf8P.png)    **Using Try and Catch I want to satisfy both condition
1) When Activity Succeeds Pipeline shows Success
2)When Activity fail then also Pipeline shows Success**

> Here Is my command that create index multiple but pipline show failure
> : when i run this command pipline show fail in mentioned picture

```
[enter image description here][1]

@CONCAT('Create Clustered index ',Item().indexname,' on  [',Item().TableSchema,'].[',Item().tableName,']([',Item().UniqueIdentifyingColumn,'])')

**
```

> NOW i want to use try  & catch  command in Azure data factory pipline
> that satisfed above mentioned second condition When Activity fail then
> also Pipeline shows Success when i tried below command facing error in
> below mentioned pic

**

```
Begin Try 

@CONCAT('Create Clustered index ',Item().indexname,' on  [',Item().TableSchema,'].[',Item().tableName,']([',Item().UniqueIdentifyingColumn,'])')

end Try 
Begin Catch
  ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 

End Catch


[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtRBI.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNzTD.png
```

Comment: Can you share a snip of whole pipeline model or how are you using this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @item directly and no need to convert to string (remove **'** **'** ), thanks to String Interpolation.

Current:

```
@CONCAT('Create Clustered index ',Item().indexname,' on  [',Item().TableSchema,'].[',Item().tableName,']([',Item().UniqueIdentifyingColumn,'])')
```

Expected :

```
Create Clustered index indexname on  TableSchema, tableName, UniqueIdentifyingColumn
```

Modify:

```
@CONCAT('Create Clustered index ', @{Item().indexname}, 'on'  @{Item().TableSchema} , @{Item().tableName}, @{Item().UniqueIdentifyingColumn})
```

**or** if you want to, use combination of variables and String() function.

Since ADF can't mix string and expression, you can only have one or the other, set the item to variable and use that as below. Then you can concatenate the ForEach activity's item to form the complete path as you need.

Example: `@concat(variables('UniqueIdentifyingColumn'), string(item().name) )`

Where Variable `UniqueIdentifyingColumn` will hold `@{Item().UniqueIdentifyingColumn}`